# react-axios-middleware promise handling

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, axios

I am working on a React application which uses `redux-axios-middleware` to do XHR requests. The way it is setup is with a client in the `index.js` like so:

```
const client = axios.create({ //all axios can be used, shown in axios documentation
  baseURL:'https://api.vktest.xxx/api',
  responseType: 'json',
  validateStatus: function (status) {
    return status >= 200 && status < 300
  }
});

const axiosMiddle = axiosMiddleware(client)

export const store = createStore(rootReducer, composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(thunk, axiosMiddle)))
```

From my component I am then calling my action like so:

`store.dispatch(loginAction(credentials))`

This is the action:

```
import { LOGIN } from './types'

export function loginAction(credentials) {

  return dispatch => {
      return dispatch(doLogin(credentials) ).then(
      response => {
        dispatch({type: 'LOGIN_SUCCESS', response})
      },
      error => {
        dispatch({type: 'LOGIN_FAIL', error})
        throw error
      }
    )
  }
}

function doLogin(credentials) {
  return {
    type: LOGIN,
    payload: {
      request: {
        url: '/login/',
        method: 'POST',
        data: {
          username: credentials.username,
          password: credentials.password
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It dispatches the doLogin function which is captured by axios-middleware to do the XHR call. After the call the axios promise contains either the type `LOGIN_SUCCESS` or `LOGIN_FAIL`. Axios automatically dispatches these types and the reducers can act on them. So far so good.

However (and I am trying to be as clear as possible), when the axios request fails, the axios promise is rejected and the `LOGIN_FAIL` type is dispatched. Since that promise is resolved the `.then(..).catch(..)` block is alway's calling the `.then`. I cannot seem to handle the axios error with doing something ugly in the `.then` block which handles the dispatch callback and not the axios callback.

To clearify the following is happening:

`store.dispatch -> action -> doLogin -> axios -> reducer -> back to action dispatch.`

I want to handle XHR errors between the axios and reducer step but when I do:

```
import { LOGIN } from './types'

export function loginAction(credentials) {

  return dispatch => {
      return dispatch(doLogin(credentials).then(
      response => {
        dispatch({type: 'LOGIN_SUCCESS', response})
      },
      error => {
        dispatch({type: 'LOGIN_FAIL', error})
        throw error
      }
    ))
  }
}

function doLogin(credentials) {
  return {
    type: LOGIN,
    payload: {
      request: {
        url: '/login/',
        method: 'POST',
        data: {
          username: credentials.username,
          password: credentials.password
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: doLogin(...).then is not a function
    at authentication.js:6
```

The reason I want to fix this is because the current setup dispatches the following:

[image: Current flow]

As seen in the image both the `LOGIN_FAIL` (axios) and the `LOGIN_SUCCESS` (dispatch) are being called. I want to be able to handle the axios error myself since I want to be able to for example give the user feedback of a failed login attempt. Somehow I am not able to figure out how.

Can someone help me?

Comment: I'm a bit baffled by what value that middleware is providing you, I'd use some promise middleware instead

Comment: Do you have an example?

Comment: Can you help me with the following issue - [link](https://github.com/svrcekmichal/redux-axios-middleware/issues/75)

I am facing unhandled promise error on success. Failure works great and never saw the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I know what you mean.

You can change that behavior by setting [returnRejectedPromiseOnError](https://github.com/svrcekmichal/redux-axios-middleware#middleware-options) in middleware config.

Note that promise is returned only to chain actions. If you set this option you will have to always apply `catch` callback or you will be getting `unhandled rejection when calling Promise` errors. And this might be causing some issues when handled in components, because these callbacks may be fired when component is already unmounted.

Im my code I try to avoid `then` as much as possible to avoid these side effects but when I have to I do it like:

```
fetchSomething.then(action => {
  if(action.type.endsWith('SUCCESS')) {
      ....
  }

})
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I did implement it but it did not change the behaviour of the middleware.

Putting `doLogin.then()` still generates the error `doLogin(...).then is not a function` and building a then/catch around the dispatch still calls `LOGIN_SUCCESS`

Comment: I did implement the if thing you posted. That works for now! Thanks.

Comment: Can you help me with the following issue - [link](https://github.com/svrcekmichal/redux-axios-middleware/issues/75)

I am facing unhandled promise error on success. Failure works great and never saw the problem